# REST API - Using a POST to read table, then send a JSON payload and receiving a response from this

Tags: java, rest, api, post, controller

Whats the best approach to use a POST method in a REST API in order to read fields from a table and then eventually convert these fields into a json payload, which will then be sent to a server expecting a response e.g. 204 if they are happy with it.

I was thinking how I could start this approach in the controller, how I would handle this 204 response, at the minute I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void readTables() throws Exception{

    //call a stored procedure to read tables and convert to JSON

   }
```

Of course there is a lot more to it, but is the RequestMethod.POST the best approach for reading tables and then sending this in one request? Or are there more steps to this within the Controller?

Comment: Where is the JSON going? To another server?

Comment: You want to read data through POST request?? I thought we had GET to do that.

Comment: @mrblewog Yes the JSON will be going to another server, and we expect a response back

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary Yes usually GET is used to read data, but in this case I want to send data as well but under one request.

Comment: @rahemd the data that you want to have, is it with you or with the third party ?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary The data is with me, I will be reading the tables in another class, I want to know if this is the best approach to use POST because when I have read a table I want to send information from there to the server.